# Repeated instances of game draw dialog box

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, tic-tac-toe

I have been working on a project of Noughts and Crosses. I once came across an irritating problem. When there is only one button left to be occupied and there are no winning moves detected so far , as a player I click on the button and the game should prompt that it is a draw. A dialog box appears and when I click ok, the same dialog box appears again. It seems to me that there is a infinite loop.  Thanks in advance

```
// make random move if above rules dont apply

Random rand1 = new Random();
Random rand2 = new Random();

int max = 2;
int min = 0;

int randnum1 = rand1.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;
int randnum2 = rand2.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;    

while( MadeMove == false) {
    while( true ) {

        if( !SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].getText().equals(SecondTest.ComputerMark) && !SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].getText().equals(SecondTest.PlayerMark))
        {
            SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].setText(SecondTest.ComputerMark);
            MadeMove = true; 

            if ( SecondTest.CheckDraw()) {
                break;
            }
            break;  
        } else {
            System.out.println("occupied");

            randnum1 = rand1.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;
            randnum2 = rand2.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;

            if (SecondTest.CheckDraw()) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}    


public static boolean CheckDraw()
{
    boolean GameDraw = true;


    for ( int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            if (cells[i][j].getText().equals(".")) {
                GameDraw = false;
            }
        }
    }


    if ( GameDraw == true  ) {
        DrawCounts++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Oh no, it's a draw! " +
                " Total Player Wins : " + PlayerCounts + " " +
                " Total Computer Wins : " + ComputerCounts + " " +
                " Total Draw Counts : " + DrawCounts + " "                  
                , "Oh no, it's a draw!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        jTextArea2.setText("It is a draw!\n To start a new game,please press Reset\n");
        gameOver = true;
        PlayerGame = false;
        AIGame = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You have a double while loop while only having one `break` notation in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of your inner loop?  Surely you want to randomly try a move until either `MadeMove` is true or a draw is detected.  You also want to move the random number generation inside the loop to reduce repetition.  Similarly coalesce the check for draw in both if and else into one check.  This should work unless the random move wins!

```
while( MadeMove == false) {
    randnum1 = rand1.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;
    randnum2 = rand2.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min ;

    if( !SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].getText().equals(SecondTest.ComputerMark) && !SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].getText().equals(SecondTest.PlayerMark)) {
        SecondTest.cells[randnum1][randnum2].setText(SecondTest.ComputerMark);
        MadeMove = true; 
    } else {
        System.out.println("occupied");
    }
    if (SecondTest.CheckDraw()) {
        break;
    }
}
```